# Show that the orthogonal projections on the coordinate axes are matrix operators

Tags: linear-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the orthogonal projections on the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, $z$-axis are defined by
$$T_1=(x,y,z)=(x,0,0)$$
$$T_2=(x,y,z)=(0,y,0)$$
$$T_3=(x,y,z)=(0,0,z)$$
respectively.

a) Show that the orthogonal projections on the coordinate axes are matrix operators, and find their standard matrices.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What can you tell us about your knowledge of this topic that will indicate where the difficulty was in answering this question?

Comment: Well if we look at $T_1$ then we have $A \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} x & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and in order to verify this $A$ should be $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Hereafter I think I should show that it is linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 transformation matrices should be 
$$
T_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\\
T_2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\\
T_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$

Here is how you can get these results.
Take $T_3$ as an example, say let 
$$ T3 = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}\\ $$
We want to solve for
$$ T3 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\z
\end{bmatrix} $$
By the rule of matrix multiplication, 
$$ T3 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z\\
a_{21} x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z\\
a_{31} x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z
\end{bmatrix} $$
So $T_3$ needs to satisfy
$$a_{11} x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z = 0$$
$$a_{21} x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z = 0$$
$$a_{31} x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z = z$$
Now we can easily solve for $T_3$. And the other two matrices are similar.